# How to create a menu as at amazon.com?

Tags: html, search, menu, drop-down-menu

I would like to create a search bar on the page that looks similar to amazon.com menu on the main page.
I'm not sure if it uses jQuery or not.

So,  contains [categories]- a drop down menu and looks like:

```
[[Drop Down Menu >] ...type text here...] [Search button]
```

Upon clicking on [Drop Down Menu] you are able to choose a state you are looking in, so your search will be within that state.

Could anybody tell me the proper way how to do that, or there is a ready source for that?
Thank you.

Comment: This is more of a "I have such and such problem" type of site.  Not a "please tell me how to do this" site.  So post what you've tried and what problems you have with it.  If you're trying to emulate Amazon, just explore the html / scripts behind it with Firebug or a smilar tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) (javascript) with some (possibly) [server-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) technology. This [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plugin for jquery may be of help.